# What's the use of the second argument on extend-protocol

Tags: clojure

What is the use of the third argument on `extend-protocol` ? Suppose I have

```
(defprotocol my-protocol 
  (foo [x]))

(extend-protocol my-protocol
  java.lang.String ; this
    (foo [x] (.length x)))

(foo "fooooo") ; 6
```

Transformed to:

```
(defprotocol my-protocol 
  (foo [x]))

(extend-protocol my-protocol
  java.lang.Long ; this
    (foo [x] (.length x)))

(foo "fooooo") ; it gave an output 6, while I expect it will throws, since I'm extending from Long, where it doesn't have length()
               ; In the end, it will just check on the args ? (in this case it's x)
```

There I gave it `java.lang.String`, if I change it to `java.lang.Long`, call on `foo` does not throw any exception, while `Long` doesn't have `length()` on it. The only case where it throws is when the argument to `foo` is doesn't have `length()`.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, if you extend your protocol to `String` and *then* to `Long`, the implementation to `String` doesn't disappear. So that's why `foo` still works on strings. But now you also have an implementation for `Long` in place that doesn't make sense, so if you call `foo` with a long, rather than tell you there's no matching implementation, Clojure will attempt to use the one you provided and run into a problem while doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `String` to `Long`, then you will get an exception when calling `foo` with a long:

```
;; calling foo with a Long:
user=> (foo 1)
IllegalArgumentException No matching field found: length for class java.lang.Long  clojure.lang.Reflector.getInstanceField (Reflector.java:271)
```

And if you don't extend your protocol to `String`, you won't be able to call `foo` on strings:

```
;; calling foo with a String with no implementation provided:
user=> (foo "asdf")
IllegalArgumentException No implementation of method: :foo of protocol: #'user/my-protocol found for class: java.lang.String  clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:537)
```

Of course if you extend `my-protocol` to `String` first and then, in a separate `extend-protocol` form, extend it again to `Long`, then `foo` will work fine with strings.

Clojure makes no attempt to determine statically whether `(.length x)` makes sense given the type you're extending your protocol too. I suppose it could in this instance, because `String` is a final class, but not in the general case (non-final class / interface) -- or at least not without changing its dynamic semantics.

Comment: I think OP wonders why there seems to be no implicit type tag on `x`, i.e. why there's no exception thrown _at compile time_ although `Long` does not have a method `length`. Any ideas on that? (Ha, you answered while I was typing. Nevermind, then. ;) )

Comment: :-) `x` is in fact implicitly type-hinted here (to the type the protocol is being extended to), but the type hint is only used to avoid reflection.

Comment: So it's just for the sake of abstraction, is that correct?

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you're asking for final clarification on the type arguments to `extend-protocol`, they are there to tell Clojure which type(s) to extend the protocol to. It's impossible to determine statically which types the given implementatioin makes sense for (if only because new types can be created dynamically at any time) and even if it were possible the programmer might not want all such extensions to be made.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk I update my question, just to be sure you get what I meant to say. Please take a look.